# Demistifying iOS device CPU usage

Tags: ios, objective-c, cpu, battery

My app use CPU so it drain battery really quick. 
I'm trying to detect what is using CPU with instruments. 
I'm running counters and i/o events but can't understand information I recieved. In counters I see only dispatch_mgr_thread at the first place. I'm hiding system libraries and have [UIApplication run] -> method from app in call three. 
Is that method the reason of CPU usage?

UPD: I've also checked app with time profiler and here is the result:
[image]

And I don't understant what is this "_dispatch_mgr_thread" or "_dispatch_worker_thread3" that works the mostly in my app even while I don't push any bottons - just start app and it does nothing.

Comment: Don't know if this helps but... : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24207590/battery-effects-of-web-apps/

Comment: usually an application runs on multiple threads, even if you don't define a new thread for your 'theoretical' background tasks.

Comment: but how to detect which methods executes in that threads? I still have cpu usae problem and trying to understand what's wrong with it.

Comment: @Maria did you ever fix your high CPU usage in `_dispatch_mgr_thread`? I'm running into the same problem when using multiple network sockets.